# Exp:resso Store - Field Instructions - How do I edit this?

Tags: expresso-store, custom-fields, expresso

Field Instructions
Instructions for authors on how or what to enter into this field when submitting an entry.

I would like to add field instruction to the "Total Stock" or "Limited Stock" field so my client will know what to enter into this field.

Were do I accomplish this, I don't see any store fields listed in the Channel Fields Admin area.

Answer (score 1):

The Store field type is one single field so you can't edit individual field labels inside unfortunately. It is done this way for ease of use as most of the inner fields are fairly self explanatory. Hopefully 'Limit Stock' will make sense to most users and once they've entered one product they'll know the drill.

Comment: Alternatively, you could edit the lang file, as long as you don't mind keeping track of your changes every time you update Store.

Comment: Although wouldn't that just edit the titles rather than add a description? But yes, it would help to clarify. @Greg, if you want to change the wording then do a search in Store > Language > English, for the title of the field you want to edit and make the change. As Adrian said though, you just need to keep this file safe when upgrading.

Comment: You're right, it would only edit the titles. Probably the only option available.

Comment: I will try and edit the title but it would be nice to be able to add a field instruction in the entry page. I find this very handy for clients that end up having a back-up person working in the CP. It's not always going to only be one person entering data in the CP.

Comment: This has helped me. I was able to edit the field names in store_lang.php.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to add a Store fieldtype to what ever channel that you want to have Store products in.

[image: Custom Fields]

You will need to simply add any instructions to the "Field Instructions" on the fieldtype settings page.

[image: Field Instructions]